# Search div for every instance of a word and replace all PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I have seen similar question to what I am about to ask but not an exact solution.
I have a div `<div class="contentSingleCol">`.
Within this div I want to search for a word and replace every instance of it with a var I have declared. It looks like I could use str_replace. I was thinking of doing something like this

```
if($bu_title) {
str_replace('Marketing', $bu_title, "This would be the div or div content?");}
```

As I am typing this I guess I have 2 questions. If using str_replace is the best solution and if so how would I declare the contents of that div as variable?

**EDIT:**

This is what I have so far

```
if($bu_title) {
echo str_ireplace('marketing', 'test', $form_url);}
```

I started with this to test, using a variable I already declared and did str_ireplace instead so it's not case sensitive.  The variable `$form_url` is a string that contains the word marketing more than once. One is capitalized and the other is not. The above code replaced both instances of "marketing" like I wanted so I think I'm on the right track but I don't want to echo the whole div. So instead I would need to do a function?

Comment: Ange where do you get the div contents from? Is it just hard-coded text in an html file?

Comment: Can you show how you use this? `str_replace()` doesn't replace by reference, so the original string is unchanged - you need to assign the result to something, and use that result instead.

Comment: You should use this code in combination with a DOM parser so you can identify div's

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yes, its a chunk of html that is being pulled into a page template which now has me thinking. I could just assign that "chunk" to a variable. The cms I am using is modx btw. This chunk/page also includes a form. I don't know if that makes a difference. So the piece I need to search are the title and the form labels.

Comment: @Qirel I updated my post

Comment: @BeetleJuice what I was thinking doesn't work. I changed my code to `echo str_ireplace('marketing', 'test', '[[*content]]');`. It echoes the content but doesn't replace the word marketing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Looked into DOM parser but using a template tag I am able to easily assign the content I want to search to a variable. Something like `$main_content = '[[*content]]';` Would I still need DOM parser?